# Why Order Api is too slow in Magento-2.1?

Tags: magento-2.1, rest-api, order-history

When I show order history using this API

> /rest/V1/orders/mine?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=customer_email&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=abc@gmail.com

It take 20-30 seconds.

How to minimize response time for this API? Please Suggest me.

Comment: I've noticed this with some Magento2 clients that we connect to via API. It sometimes takes several minutes!!! Since I don't have direct access to their servers I cannot tell, but I suspect it is a missing or incorrect database index causing Magento to do a full table scan.

Answer (score 0):

See my answer [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/234771/i-want-to-some-attributes-in-response-of-v1-products-sku-api-how-can-be-get-sp/281272#281272)

If possible, limit not only the fields returned but also the date range, via "created_at", that is searched.

Paging, as described [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/rest/performing-searches.html#other-search-criteria), will also speed up responses, but be aware that Magento may return duplicate results if an invalid page number is specified.